# Java garbage collector execution

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Finalize methods are invoked by the garbage collector prior to reclaiming the memory occupied by the object, which has the finalize() method. This means you do not know when the objects are going to be finalized.

Why we dont know when garbage collector will run. Does the founders of Java also dont know this. There will be a specific condition or time (for sure) when garbage collector will run.

Answer (score 2):

> Why we dont know when garbage collector will run.

It is a deliberate design choice.  This gives the JVM the flexibility to do garbage collection at a time (and in a way) that gives optimal performance, or minimal pauses ... depending on the collector that the user has chosen.

> There will be a specific condition or time (for sure) when garbage collector will run.

No.

The only thing that it is pretty much guaranteed is that a full GC will be run before the JVM decides to "give up" and throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.

There is a `System.gc()` method that you can call to *suggest* to the JVM that it should run a garbage collection.  However:

- The JVM is allowed to ignore the suggestion.
- If the JVM pays attention to the suggestion, your application is liable to perform worse than if you just let the JVM decide.  Calling `System.gc()` in production code is nearly always a BAD IDEA.

---

The bottom line is that if you want to guarantee that a certain action happens, you should not implement that action using a finaliser.

Comment: +1 I would add that any exception thrown by the code running in a finalizer will be swallowed and the code will die silently, resulting in hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

When the garbage collection is done is down to the implementation but it will usually happen when the free memory has reached below a certain threshold.

I remember hearing that it is allowed for an implementation to have no garbage collection at all!

You will not be able to tell for sure when the collection will happen without knowing the implementation details and then monitoring whatever it is that the GC is monitoring. But even this will have problems and it is highly discouraged as it completely defeats the portability  of Java.

The is a method [`System.gc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) which:

> suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

However use of this is also discouraged.